# Conditional formatting in PowerBi with columns instead of value

Tags: powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting

We are moving few data from qlik to PowerBi. As a newbie, I'm stuck with conditional formatting where I need to divide two columns and compare with another column.
For example:

```
If(divide(column A,column B)>column c,"red","green")
```

Please help explain how I can derive a conditional format using this?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken some sample data and shown how to do conditional formatting.

Write a measure

```
Measure = if(DIVIDE(SUM('Table'[Column1]), SUM('Table'[Column2])) < SUM('Table'[Column3]), 1,0)

Measure 2 = DIVIDE(SUM('Table'[Column1]), SUM('Table'[Column2]))
```

[image]